# Sum of Particular Column in sql by selecting from date and to date

Tags: sql, windows

The table structure I currently have is like this:

```
Category   Date        GrandTotal
-----------------------------------    
Cat1       26/2/2013      900
Cat1       26/2/2013      200
Cat2       26/2/2013      100
Cat2       27/2/2013      150
Cat2       28/2/2013      200
```

But I'm looking to get it like this:

If I select the Transaction from `26/2/2013` to `26/2/2013`

I should get the total amount for `26th February` only, so the result should be 1200.

Can any one please tell me the SQL query for this?

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? SQL-Server? Access? Oracle? MySQL? Firebird? There are so many, ὧν οὐκ ἔστιν ἀριθμός.

Comment: If none of the answers are correct could you provide more information on what you want.  Or accept an answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT sum(GrandTotal) FROM table WHERE Date = '26/2/2013'
```

Or if you wanted to do a range you could do `> '25/2/2013' and < '27/2/2013'`

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this code

```
SELECT DATE,SUM(GRANDTOTAL) FROM TABLE_NAME
GROUP BY DATE
HAVING DATE BETWEEN 26/2/2013 AND 26/2/2013
```